# How to make a multi-color gradient in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, gradient

[image: **enter image description here**]

Hello, I was wondering what it takes to make this blurred and blended type of multi colored gradient in photoshop? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't see why this is getting downvoted. it is a useful, canonical question on gradients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Photoshop:

- Create a new document
- Create a shape
- Go to FX

[image]

- Gradient Overlay

[image]

- Click the the current gradient

[image]

- Create a new gradient

[image]

- Add color to the gradient path and you might want to use the color picker to find the colors

[image]

- Change the style to `linear`

[image]

Play around with the colors:

[image]